# ResultSet empty when using createArrayOf in Java with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, prepared-statement, sqlconnection

I'm trying to query *product* table using an array of `id`s. Here's a fragment of the method:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection
    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (?)");

System.out.println(ids /*ArrayList<Integer>*/); //prints [3]

Array array = connection.createArrayOf("INTEGER", ids.toArray());
// Array array = connection.createArrayOf("INTEGER", new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}); //<-----tried this too

statement.setArray(1, array);

ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();

while (results.next()) {
    System.out.println("does not print this");
    Product product = new Product(0);
    product.setId(results.getInt("id"));
    products.add(product);
}

return products;
```

Table `product` contains 3 rows with `id`s 1, 2 and 3. `products` returns null. Any idea why?

Thanks

EDIT

According to [section 9.23.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR)

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions

example `(1,2,3)`

So, I think question turns into: how to get that list of scalar expressions from my `ArrayList`?

Comment: This is not how you populate an SQL set. You have to provide the appropriate number of `?` markers and set values for them manually. An SQL Array is a completely different beast.

Comment: ok, so that's how I *don't* do it. now, how *might* I do it? any examples, snippets, resources, pointers, signals? thanks

Comment: Have you tried: 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ANY(?)' and does your query work, using the psql client?

Comment: @SimonSchiff make that an answer, get your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check in the WHERE clause of a query, whether an element is in an array you can use ANY. In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ANY(?)
```